# Beginners advice for process and tooling to make small PCBs

Tags: pcb, soldering

I've made a circuit that consists of many op amps and several other components. I soldered it on a simple PCB board but I'm worried about short circuits or physical damage when placed in a box.

Its size could also use some reduction since it's a portable application. I've never done PCB printing before so I have a lot to learn in this matter.

From what I understood, the available tools help you by printing the boards and you connect the parts afterwards by soldering them. Are there tools that will make the whole circuit with the components mounted? I've also read about SMD parts, do they normally come with the printed boards or do I have to order them separately?

Finally, they mentioned something about the thickness of the board, how do I decide on a certain thickness?

You can just point out the name of the tools and I'll do the research (I just don't know what to search for).

Comment: Unfortunately this is far too broad for the mission of this site.  Ultimately there are a wide range of options, but looking at a constrained small-order batch service like OSH park may give you an idea of what is most common.  You can make PCBs yourself by mechanical engraving, photo etching, or heat transfer of laser printer toner as an etch resist, but these tend to be less reliable and even more limited, so only really sensible when there is an extreme time urgency.  SMD parts are typically used on fully custom boards, though there are some generic and semi-custom breakouts.

Comment: Thank you chris, I've came across most of these methods in my search, but I need a reliable way that will enable me to print a large number of the same board (it might be commercialized if approved). I appreciate your reply though and thanks again.

Comment: Unless you mean to make your business (ie the focus of your attention) the production of other people's boards rather than the design of your own, the only reliable way to get lots of boards is to pay a board fabrication service to make them for you.

Comment: alright I get you, thank very much

Answer (score 2):

By your description, you seem to have multiple steps merged together.

The usual steps are:

1. Using an appropriate CAD program (Eagle or KiCAD, for example), draw your schematic and produce a netlist. (somewhere around here you associate PCB footprints with the schematic components) (also, choose specific parts, ensure they are available in the package you want, think about an enclosure for the product...)
2. In the PCB design part of the CAD package, read in the netlist, place componens on the board (an image on the screen at this point), and draw the necessary tracks to interconnect the parts.
3. When the board layout is complete, produce the Gerber photoplot files and drill file that the board shop will use to make your bare board.  Order the boards.
4. When you get the bare boards, install the parts on one or two boards, and test them for proper operation.
5. If if doesn't work, go to Step 1, make corrections, order more boards...etc.
6. For quantity production, find an assembly shop to build the boards for you.

I'm sure I've left out some vital steps.

Comment: Step 0: find/choose a PCB manufacturer.  Step 1.5 enclosure and mechanical design, and all the planning for wiring connectors and connections.  Step 0.5: learning 'Eagle or Kicad' takes a week or two.

Comment: yes I thought it was a simple design then order process. Thank you very much I really appreciate it. I'll do more research on the designing tools and manufacturers and hopefully all will go as planned.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a PCB with the solder mask and everything, your going to have to use a PCB manufacturing service. The main method for producing PCB's for prototyping is CNC mills or lasers, they cut or etch a copper board. I've done this before at home, but I only do it for fun. And you can achieve 2 mil resolution or with a more expensive mill 1 mil or less. (The milling bits are expensive and break a lot too) The cost of a CNC mill and tooling is min ~500 USD. Even if you made 50 boards to bring the cost down to 10$ a board, your going to sink an hour or two for each board. Save yourself the time and money and use a design service.

Comment: yes it seems like that's what I will do, thanks very much

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I use:

KiCAD EDA to design PCB's

FlatCAM to generate g-code from PCB design

3020 Router with Mach3 for routing board [Here is Link](http://www.ebay.com/itm/3-AXIS-3020T-USB-CNC-ROUTER-ENGRAVER-CUTTING-CUTTER-ARTWORK-CARVING-TOOL-GOOD-/152365387337?hash=item2379af4e49:g:lb8AAOSw44BYYeIl)

Here is an example of what I have gotten from this process:

[image: Example Board]

Comment: so do you suggest  buying the router and doing it at home? this would be very expensive, from all the feedback, using the traditional design, order, install process is my best option. Thanks very much!